# Replace a loop to count the number elements matching a criteria

Tags: c++, lambda

Could we replace a loop with a strcmp by something easier to read, something similar to the C# extension methods?

I maintain legacy C++ and wonder how to start a transition to a more modern C++ and there is profusion of code that looks like this one:

```
int numberOfPipe = 10;
char* collection[5] = { "pompe","pipe","turbine","pompe", "pipe" };

// Count the pipes in the collection

int nPipeFound = 0;
int nPipe = 5;

for (int idx = 0; idx < nPipe; idx++)
{
    if (strcmp(collection[idx], "pipe") == 0)
        nPipeFound++;
}

cout << nPipeFound << endl;
```

Comment: Well, if you use std::string, you don't need strcmp ... or you could write your own comparison which makes the code more complicated for no reason. Btw., that isn't related to lambdas at all.

Comment: `auto nPipeFound = std::count_if(std::begin(collection), std::end(collection), [](const char* s) { return strcmp(s, "pipe") == 0; });`

Comment: @DanielSchepler Why not just `std::count( std::begin( collection ), std::end( collection ), "pipe")`?

Comment: @HenriMenke That would compare the literal pointers for equality, which could end up returning 0 (or might return 2, if the compiler does a "constant string pooling" optimization).  I suppose `std::count(std::begin(collection), std::end(collection), std::string{"pipe"})` could work though.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Ah, I see. Thank you!  I was hoping that there was an overload for `char const *` to have proper string comparison.

Comment: @HenriMenke there is such overload, but you tried to compare `const char *` with another `const char *`

Comment: @Less White Note, that switching to template code will make this particular code larger (in compiled binary), it'll compile longer, and it probably will be a little bit slower. So be careful when "upgrading" a working old style c++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the standard library:

1. Use `std::count` and use the `std::string` comparison.

   ```
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   int main() {
     char const * collection[] = { "pompe","pipe","turbine","pompe","pipe" };

     auto n_pipe_found = std::count( std::begin( collection ), std::end( collection ), std::string{"pipe"});

     std::cout << n_pipe_found << '\n';
   }
   ```
2. Use `std::count_if` and write a predicate which does C string comparison for you.

   ```
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <cstring>
   #include <iostream>

   int main() {
     char const * collection[] = { "pompe","pipe","turbine","pompe","pipe" };

     auto n_pipe_found = std::count_if( std::begin( collection ), std::end( collection ),
                                        [](char const * a) { return std::strcmp(a,"pipe") == 0; } );

     std::cout << n_pipe_found << '\n';
   }
   ```

   You could also use a predicate like `[](std::string const& a) { return a == "pipe"; }` and again make use of `std::string` comparison.
3. Use `std::accumulate` if you need more fine grained control over counting.

   ```
   #include <numeric>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   int main() {
     char const * collection[] = { "pompe","pipe","turbine","pompe","pipe" };

     auto n_pipe_found = std::accumulate( std::begin( collection ), std::end( collection ), int{0},
                                      [](int a, std::string const& b) { return a + (b == "pipe"); });

     std::cout << n_pipe_found << '\n';
   }
   ```

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 complains  the namespace "std" has no member "accumulate". Do I miss something?

Comment: @LessWhite Try with `#include <numeric>` instead of `#include <algorithm>`.  Apparently VS handles it a little different than GCC.

Comment: @LessWhite That you need a better, or at least newer, compiler. (I mean that without a joke). While MS is trying and even improving, full language support still isn't something they're known for.

Comment: @HenriMenke As DanielSchepler just explained above, you code isn't what OP (probably) wants. edit: And now it's just strange and wrong

Comment: Thanks so much, this is so useful!

Comment: @LessWhite If you use this code, please see the mentioned comment of DanielSchepler too, because HenriMenge failed to copy-paste it correctly.

Comment: Why this convoluted use of `std::accumulate` when there is `std::count_if`?

Comment: @deviantfan: Visual Studio is standard compliant here. `std::accumulate` is in the `<numeric>` header, as it's supposed to be.